# Preserve associated row data while using importRange in the destination sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

For our construction company, we have a sheet that has all of the bills listed, along with relevant data that our accounting person would add to the [master sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pY53-XaGnUQ3BPmLh90mLSqIwSo7S2_QOPbD6JBQHOA/edit#gid=0).

I then have another sheet that pulls this data for the relevant people in the accounts for them to complete those steps. It filters to only the relevant columns (specifically, based on Column H - either "Yes" or "No") using query and importRange.

```
query(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pY53-XaGnUQ3BPmLh90mLSqIwSo7S2_QOPbD6JBQHOA/edit#gid=0","Master!A3:G"), "Select Col1, Col2, Col4, Col5, Col6, Col7 where Col6 is not null")
```

I want to include a few details in the [destination sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oVEV8RAJGnisP_6lJMmGfyu8N-AKMXHhEczVMtjDYkA/edit#gid=0), which I have done.

The problem is typically associated with column H in the master sheet (Work Done required or not). For most cases, it is either a yes or no. However, in some cases, the accounting person doesn't know for sure whether it is a yes or no. But he wants to keep on adding other bill details.

When he fills the empty column later, the entered data on this second sheet doesn't dynamically shift with the imported data, thus causing the rows to misalign.

Unfortunately, as I mentioned, the rows don't stick together so as the dynamic order of the imported columns changes, the static order of the manual columns causes a mismatch.

Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: First of call, it is not advise to reveal all your company `P&C` information here, try to create a sheet with mock data. Forum is ready to help, but you have to help you company also...

Comment: Hi, this is a mock data that is shared @kin

Comment: This is the most commonly asked question on how to use spreadsheets.  No there is no "good" way to make it work.  What you need is database software rather than spreadsheets unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

A solution would be to add an `onEdit` trigger in order to check if any changes have been made to the `H` column and later add the corresponding rows to the destination sheet, something similar to this:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  let destinationSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SS_ID").getSheetByName('Input Sheet');
  let sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  let lastRow = destinationSheet.getLastRow();
  if (e.range.getColumn() == 8 && e.range.getValue() != null) {
    let billNo = sourceSheet.getRange(e.range.getRow(),1).getValue();
    // retrieve all the other values needed from the current row of the edit
    // current row of the edit > e.range.getRow()
    destinationSheet.getRange(lastRow+1,1).setValue(billNo);
    // copying the values to the destination sheet by using setValue()

  } 
}
```

The above code makes use of the `e` event object in order to check if the edit has been made in the `H` column and if the value is different from `null`. If this condition checks, the values needed to be copied are being retrieved (here I have illustrated how to retrieve the `billNo`) and later set them in the destination sheet by retrieving the last row of it.

#### Note

You can also add a `for` loop in order to manage the copying the data easier and also add more conditions such that it the new entry is being pasted after a certain `Actual Date` or simply sort the values after the entry is being pasted.

#### Reference

- [Apps Script Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite);
- [Apps Script Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events);
- [Apps Script Range Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range).

Comment: this answer gives me a starting point.

However, in the destination sheet, the corresponding columns can have values. Those need to be retrieved as well. Can you show me a way to do that?

Comment: You will have to use something similar to: `destinationSheet.getRange(RANGE_FROM_THE_SHEET_WHERE_THE_VALUES_ARE).getValues()`

Answer (score 0):

I have performed testing with the following formula, I found no issue even I remove certain value for certain cell in "Col H", and the result is still correct, am I miss out certain information? I just change the filter criteria based on `Col H` only

```
=query(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pY53-XaGnUQ3BPmLh90mLSqIwSo7S2_QOPbD6JBQHOA/edit#gid=0","Master!A3:H"),"Select Col1, Col2, Col4, Col5, Col6, Col7 where Col8 is not null")
```

Comment: Hi @kin siang

let's say i filter by Col H to destination sheet. I need to fill in additional details in the destination sheet corresponding to fetched rows.

Let us say there are 10 rows in source sheet. row 3 and row 4 does not have ColH values. Therefore, other rows are fetched to destination for the time being where i fill in other details. Once, I put in Col H data of row 3 and 4, the associated data in destination sheet gets misaligned.

Comment: ok, i get your issue now, let me think how to solve this issue, because your `actual date` and `status` is plain text

Comment: Why you cannot add one new column for the `actual date` and to `query` the table including `actual date` later, since `done` is always confirm same and as long as your source data are all correct, then you won't need to worry about the alignment of the row? If not possible, then you should create one `master list for actual date`, so when you `query` the table, you can `vlookup actual date & status` from the master list. The master list contain all `bill no` by `copy paste value`.

Comment: Did the solution provided in the comment above work for your situation? @AbhikPaul

Comment: nope, that does not work for me. because my concern is the mismatch of associated rows in the destination sheet

also, the data will be like a front end for employees, therefore associated rows details are input by the employees in the destination sheet

Comment: Would you be willing to consider a script solution in this situation then? @AbhikPaul

Comment: @ale13 if that helps, I am open to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some Apps Script code (custom function + installable trigger) to solve this problem.

https://github.com/giantswarm/gapps-automation/tree/main/sticky-rows

It aligns two ranges on one sheet by performing something like an INNER JOIN using the first ranges ID colum (must be first column).

This way dynamic data (eg. from `IMPORTRANGE()` or `QUERY()`) can be used alongside user edited cells without falling apart, when row count or row order in the dynamic range change.