# How can i remove automatically infos associated to an importrange list when i remove an item from the source sheet (Sheets)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm working with google Sheets and I have a sheet call *source Sheet* where names are listed in Column A

```
ColumnA
John
Peter
etc
```

In a separate sheet (target sheet), i import this list'names (column A) and associate other information regarding each person.

Like this :
in cell A2 of *Target sheet*, i put this formula

```
=importrange("ID sheet";"source Sheet!A2:A")
```

So i get the same list which is what i wanted. To that list, i associated a couple of additional information regarding to each of them like

```
*Target Sheet*
Column A = names    Column B = Age     Column C = Occupation     etc
```

When i remove a person in the source sheet, the target sheet is updated but the information which was associated to that person stays in the target sheet.

What can i do to remove automatically the info asoociated to a person (target sheet) once i remove someone from the Source sheet ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Preserve associated row data while using importRange in the destination sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67847516/preserve-associated-row-data-while-using-importrange-in-the-destination-sheet)

Comment: Thx for the quick answer The Master. I'm going to take a look at it and come back to you.